# Validations with Data Annotations in Entity Framework do not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form made in Asp.NET MVC using Entity Framework for persistence and using data annotations to validate the fields. The problem I have is that the validations do not work. I want show alert when user try to save null values.

```
throw new System.Exception (errorMessage);
```

Of the controller and to look at the detail says:

> Entity of type "Student" in state "Added" has the following validation errors:
>   - Property: "StudentName", Error: "The StudentNameName field is required."
>   - Property: "StudentGeneral", Error: "The StudentGeneral field is required."

What's going on? I have these lines in my `web.config`:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Controller:

```
using Lista.Models;
using Lista6.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Lista6.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private StudentEntities db = new StudentEntities();

        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var student = new Student();

            var items = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Male", Value = "Male"},
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Female", Value = "Female"},
            };

            ViewData["Genders"] = items;

            return View(student);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "StudentId,StudentName,StudentGender")] Student stu)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    db.Student.Add(stu);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    string errorMessage = "";

                    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        errorMessage = string.Format("\nEntity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            errorMessage += string.Format("\n- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }

                    throw new System.Exception(errorMessage);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Create", "Home");
            }

            return View(stu);
        }
    }
}
```

Student.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Lista6.Models;

namespace Lista.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(StudentMetaData))]
    public partial class Student
    {
    }

    public enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female
    }
}
```

StudentMetaData.cs

```
using Lista.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Lista6.Models
{
    public class StudentMetaData
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Gender StudentGender { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model Student
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<br />
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentGender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("StudentGender", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Genders"], "Select Gender", new { @class = "form-control" })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentGender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: `I want to put fields with null value, I want to save the fields` so you want to be able to save null values into your database ? is that what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, clarify your issue. Those 2 fields are marked required so it should throw the exception if they are missing.

Comment: I had edited quetion